# How long can I keep a socket open in Amazon cloud?

Tags: java, cloud

Do you know how long I can keep a socket open with my browser/mobile app in Amazon cloud? Can you point me to a documentation?

Thanks,

Sean Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it open for as long as you dont' read EOS from it and don't get IOException: connection reset when writing to it.